# Etymology of the "Chicago Seven" construction

Tags: etymology, history

There are many examples of a construction of the form "City + Number" used to refer to an incident involving a particular small group of people.  It is often used when it is alleged that the people in question are the victims of some sort of injustice.

Examples:

- [Little Rock Nine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Rock_Nine): nine schoolchildren whose attempt to enroll in a segregated school in Little Rock, Arkansas in 1957 required the involvement of Army paratroopers.
- [Chicago Seven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Seven): seven defendants charged with crimes (later acquitted) for their alleged involvement in the protests surrounding the 1968 Democratic National Convention in Chicago.
- [Birmingham Six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmingham_Six): Six men convicted of bombing pubs in Birmingham, England in 1975, whose convictions were later overturned.

I am curious about the origins of this usage.  What is the first known example?  Was there a "prototype" case which later examples were consciously modeled upon?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain, or suggest improvements?  I have done my best to state the question clearly, I hope it is useful, and I am unsure where I would start in trying to research it.  (Google for "city number" is unhelpful for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Very interesting question. I think _city_ is probably a bit of a herring, since counties, countries, provinces, and other similar areas should work just as well (though I admit I can think of no examples). As a more or less random idea, I wonder if there might possibly be some connection with [_Seven against Thebes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Against_Thebes) somehow …

Comment: It's certainly a snowclone. 'The Tamworth Two' (aka Butch and Sundance) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamworth_Two)) provided a bit of relief from the usual bad news broadcast in 1998. 'Babylon 5' and the 'Chiltern Hundreds' are sadly not ancient members of the snowclone.

Comment: I think it originated with the Indianapolis 500

Comment: Wikipedia has: 'The American Five was a group of modernist American composers consisting of Charles Ives, John J. Becker, Wallingford Riegger, Henry Cowell, and Carl Ruggles. It was known for its modernist and often dissonant compositions which broke away from European compositional styles to create a distinctly American style. The name was coined in imitation of the group of Russian composers called _The Five_.'

Comment: holy crap - is that the only two-word snowclone?

Comment: @Nate - regarding the downvoting, voting on this site is incoherent/random, so forget it

Answer (score 3):

### 1879...

Checking Wikipedia's [Quantified groups of defendants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Quantified_groups_of_defendants), the oldest is the [Blue Eyed Six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Eyed_Six) from 1879, but they were coincidentally all blue-eyed. Here's a [contemporary newspaper report](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88061082/1879-08-16/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1836&sort=date&date2=1922&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=1&words=blue+eyed+six&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=Blue+Eyed+Six&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1).

### 1931?

There's the [Scottsboro Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottsboro_nine) from 1931, but it seems that was a later label and they were called the Scottsboro Boys at the time.

### 1948?

The [Groveland Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groveland_Four) from 1948, but seems they were referred to as the Groveland Boys at the time.

### 1948-1949

The [Trenton Six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trenton_Six) from 1948 were referred to as such [at least in 1949](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trenton_Six#Further_reading), if not earlier.

> The Trenton Six case arose in 1948 in Trenton, New Jersey, when six African American defendants were convicted by an all-white jury of the murder of an elderly white shopkeeper.

### 1949-1951

The [Martinsville Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martinsville_Seven) arrested in 1949, labelled as such at least in [1951](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,820649,00.html).

> The Martinsville Seven were a group of seven African-American men who were executed in the electric chair for the gang rape of a white woman in the state of Virginia, United States. They were arrested in 1949 and executed in 1951. It was the largest mass execution for rape that had been reported, and has been compared to a lynching.

Comment: Aha!  "Quantified groups of defendants."  I would never have guessed to search for that.  Thanks, this is a very big step.

Comment: it's like "there's an app for that!"  "there's a wiki page for that!"  good grief!